# Transmission app update

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, transmission

I noticed the Transmission app in Lubuntu 20.04 currently updates to version 3.00.
Meanwhile Kubuntu 20.04 doesn't offer its update, staying with 2.94 version.
Tell me please, when would some changes with Kubuntu become?

Comment: Both Ubuntu and Kubuntu and Lubuntu and all other flavors use exactly the same deb package for Transmission. For 20.04, that's version 2.94. Newer releases (21.10 and 22.04) use version 3.00. If you are really using Lubuntu 20.04 (not 22.04) with Transmission 3.00, then please edit your question to include the output of `cat /etc/*release` and of `apt-cache policy transmission`

Comment: Perhaps you added a PPA for Transmission and forgot about it?

Answer (score 1):

All of Ubuntu systems (be they Ubuntu, or *flavors* such as Lubuntu, or Kubuntu) use the same repositories; which have

`transmission | 2.94-2ubuntu3     | focal/universe           | all`

for *focal* or 20.04.

Both Kubuntu & Lubuntu have the same version;so check where you've grabbed your Lubuntu version from; as it's not a Ubuntu *focal* or 20.04 source.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=transmission&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

All *flavors* are sourced from main Ubuntu ('main') and 'universe' (community sourced) and thus have the same packages.

> ```
> focal (20.04LTS) (net): lightweight BitTorrent client [universe]
> 2.94-2ubuntu3: all
> ```